# tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternaalError:BLAS GEMM launch failed: a.shpe=(8, 459), b.shape=(8, 2), m=459, n=2, k=8

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, memory, gpu

I am trying to train a CNN model on gpu with tensorflow-gpu2.0.0, and a error occurred as title mentioned, It can run well on cpu with tensorflow2.0.0. I use cuda 10.0, cudnn 7.6.5, RTX 3080(10GB).
I couldn't find out which part is wrong, I saw some issues similar with this, they said it was caused by the memory occupation of process, so I tried to add

```
gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
tf.config.experimental.set_virtual_device_device_configuration(gpus[0], [tf.config.experimental.VirtualDeviceConfiguration(memory_limit=1024)])
```

behind `import tensorflow as tf`, but it didn't work to this, reduce batch_size didn't work as well.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard, ModelCheckpoint, ReduceLROnPlateau, EarlyStopping
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import time
import datetime
import os
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
import pickle
import numpy as np
from Fusion_layer import perception_layer_topologyV1_template
from loss_2 import Custom_loss
import math



class am_lfs():

    def __init__(self, M=6, sigma=0.2, epochs=1, batch_size=128, B=4, num_class=2, Dropout_rate=0.3):
        self.M = M
        self.sigma = sigma
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.Dropout_rate = Dropout_rate
        self.B = B
        self.epochs = epochs
        self.num_class = num_class
        self.train_set = train_dataset
        self.test_set = test_dataset

    def train_model(self, model, early_stopping, csv_logger, train_set, test_set, sear, i, train_dataset, test_dataset):
        print("training model...")
        history = model.fit(train_dataset,
                              steps_per_epoch = max(1, math.ceil(len(train_set) / self.batch_size)),                       
                              epochs=epochs,
                              validation_data = test_dataset,                 #remember to change it
                              validation_steps = max(1, math.ceil(len(test_set) / self.batch_size)),
                              callbacks=[early_stopping, csv_logger])  
        path1 = 'model{}_{}.h5'.format(i, sear)
        model.save(os.path.join(result_path,path1))
        return history


    def Mymodel(self, theta):
        inputs = layers.Input(shape=(112, 112, 1), name='input')  # shape of input
        x = inputs
        # normal convolution layers
        output = layers.Conv2D(137, (7, 7), strides=2, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)

        output = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=2, padding='same')(output)

        output = layers.Conv2D(137, (1, 1))(output)

        output = layers.Conv2D(144, (3, 3), padding='same')(output)

        output = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3), strides=2, padding='same')(output)

        # Inception module (fusion 3)
        output = perception_layer_topologyV1_template(output, output_size=245, convMM_size=2, convMM_num=24,
                                             num_of_c11_1=308, conv1_size=6, conv1_num=77,
                                             num_of_c11_2=24, conv2_size=7, conv2_num=24,
                                             pool1_size=2, num_of_pool1c1_max=40, num_of_pool1c1_min=40,
                                             pool2_size=5, num_of_pool2c1_max=20, num_of_pool2c1_min=20,
                                             name="fusion_3")

        # Inception module (fusion 4)
        output = perception_layer_topologyV1_template(output, output_size=228, convMM_size=2, convMM_num=35,
                                             num_of_c11_1=354, conv1_size=6, conv1_num=15,
                                             num_of_c11_2=281, conv2_size=7, conv2_num=13,
                                             pool1_size=2, num_of_pool1c1_max=24, num_of_pool1c1_min=23,
                                             pool2_size=5, num_of_pool2c1_max=59, num_of_pool2c1_min=59,
                                             name="fusion_4")

        # max_pool
        output = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=[3, 3],strides =2, padding = 'same', name = 'pool2')(output)

        # Inception module (fusion 5)
        output = perception_layer_topologyV1_template(output, output_size=459, convMM_size=2, convMM_num=14,
                                             num_of_c11_1=46, conv1_size=3, conv1_num=25,
                                             num_of_c11_2=170, conv2_size=5, conv2_num=116,
                                             pool1_size=4, num_of_pool1c1_max=107, num_of_pool1c1_min=107,
                                             pool2_size=5, num_of_pool2c1_max=45, num_of_pool2c1_min=45,
                                             name="fusion_5")
        # AveragePooling
        output = layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=[7, 7], strides=1, name='aver_pool_1')(output)
        # Flatten
        # output = layers.Flatten()(output)
        # Dropout
        output = layers.Dropout(self.Dropout_rate)(output)
        output = tf.squeeze(output, axis=2)
        output1 = tf.squeeze(output, axis=1, name='output1')
        # Dense: activation - softmax
        # logits = MyLayer(2)           # original FC
        logits = layers.Dense(2, activation='elu', name='output')(output1)

        # Build model
        model = keras.Model(inputs, logits)
        model.summary()
        w = model.layers[-1].get_weights()
        w_1 = tf.cast(w[0], dtype=tf.float32, name='w_1')
        model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss=Custom_loss(theta, w_1, output1), metrics=['accuracy'],
                      experimental_run_tf_function = False
                      )
        return model

class idk():
    def __init__(self, mus, B, M, sigma, dist):
        self.mus = mus
        self.B = B
        self.optim_mus = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.05) 
        self.dist =dist

    def sample(self):
        self.thetas = self.dist.sample((self.B,))
        return self.thetas

    def run(self, dict_m, thetas):
        accs = []
        loss_mu = 0
        with tf.GradientTape() as Tape:
            Tape.watch(self.mus)
            for i in range(self.B):
                max_acc = dict_m['Max_acc{}'.format(i)]
                acc = dict_m['acc{}'.format(i)]
                accs += acc
                loss_mu -= dist.log_prob(thetas[i]) * (max_acc - np.mean(accs)) / (np.std(accs) + np.finfo(np.float32).eps.item())
            loss_mu = loss_mu/self.B
        grad = Tape.gradient(loss_mu, [self.mus])
        self.optim_mus.apply_gradients(zip(grad, [self.mus,]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if not os.path.exists(r'.\logs\search\{}'.format(datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y%m%d"))):
        os.mkdir(r'.\logs\search\{}'.format(datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y%m%d")))
    result_path = r'.\logs\search\{}'.format(datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y%m%d"))

    start_time = time.time()
    batch_size = 128
    epochs = 1
    last_acc = 0.995
    B=4
    M=6
    sigma=0.25
    sear = 0
    dict_m = {}  
    
    train_dataset =...
    print("train data loaded...")

    # callbacks
    early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy', min_delta=0.003, patience=3, verbose=1)        

    for i in range(B):
        dict_m['csv_logger{}'.format(str(i))] = tf.keras.callbacks.CSVLogger(r".\logs\csv\training_model{}_{}.log.csv".format(str(i), datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")), append=True)
      

    # start training
    Am_Lfs = am_lfs(M=6, sigma=0.2, epochs=1, batch_size=128, B=4, num_class=2, Dropout_rate=0.3)
    mus = tf.Variable(tf.convert_to_tensor(np.concatenate([np.ones([6, ]), np.zeros([6, ])])), dtype=tf.float64, name='mus')
    dist = tfp.distributions.MultivariateNormalDiag(mus, tf.cast(np.ones(2 * M) * sigma, dtype=tf.float64))
    thetas = idk(mus, B, M, sigma, dist).sample()

    for i in range(B):
        model = Am_Lfs.Mymodel(thetas[i])
        dict_m["m{}".format(str(i))] = model

    for epo in range(200):
        sear = sear + 1
        max_acc_list = []
        for i in range(B):
            history = Am_Lfs.train_model(dict_m["m{}".format(str(i))], early_stopping, dict_m["csv_logger{}".format(str(i))], train_set, test_set, sear, i,
                                                        train_dataset, test_dataset)
            val_acc = history.history['val_accuracy']
            dict_m['acc{}'.format(i)] = val_acc
            dict_m['Max_acc{}'.format(i)] = max(val_acc)
            max_acc_list.append(dict_m['Max_acc{}'.format(i)])
          
        idk(mus, B, M, sigma, dist).run(dict_m, thetas)  
        dist = tfp.distributions.MultivariateNormalDiag(mus, tf.cast(np.ones(2 * M) * sigma, dtype=tf.float64))  
        thetas = idk(mus, B, M, sigma, dist).sample()   

        index, value = np.argmax(max_acc_list), np.max(max_acc_list)
        model_path = os.path.join(result_path, 'model{}_{}.h5'.format(index, sear))

        for i in range(B):
            dict_m["m{}".format(str(i))].load_weights(model_path)

    end_time = time.time()
    print('time_cost(s)：', end_time - start_time)
```

here is the error if it helps

```
2022-02-25 10:05:38.104299: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_100.dll
2022-02-25 10:06:35.446853: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2022-02-25 10:17:34.713995: W tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/redzone_allocator.cc:312] Internal: Invoking ptxas not supported on Windows
Relying on driver to perform ptx compilation. This message will be only logged once.
2022-02-25 10:17:34.956997: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:428] failed to run cuBLAS routine: CUBLAS_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED
2022-02-25 10:17:34.957108: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/base_collective_executor.cc:216] BaseCollectiveExecutor::StartAbort Internal: Blas GEMM launch failed : a.shape=(8, 459), b.shape=(8, 2), m=459, n=2, k=8
  [[{{node training/Adam/gradients/gradients/output/MatMul_grad/MatMul_1}}]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\py37tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 511, in call
    ctx=ctx)
  File "D:\anaconda3\envs\py37tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\execute.py", line 67, in quick_execute
    six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError:  Blas GEMM launch failed : a.shape=(8, 459), b.shape=(8, 2), m=459, n=2, k=8
  [[node training/Adam/gradients/gradients/output/MatMul_grad/MatMul_1 (defined at \anaconda3\envs\py37tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py:1751) ]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_5416]

Function call stack:
keras_scratch_graph
```

Comment: Post the full error trace. That would provide some helpful context

Comment: CUBLAS_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED means the program failed to execute on GPU. This is due to launch failure of the kernel on the GPU. I am assuming you are using NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080 not GTX 3080 card. For this GPU card, support starts from CUDA 11.x. Once you upgrade Tensorflow >= TF2.4, will resolve your issue. Thanks!